# Error in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, debugging

I am trying to do a simple INSERT, but I keep on getting this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM,TO,ID,CURRENCY1,CURRENCY2,AMOUNT,NOTE,RATE) VALUES('test', 'test2', 'dd', '' at line 2

Here is my code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO WIRET
    (FROM,TO,ID,CURRENCY1,CURRENCY2,AMOUNT,NOTE,RATE) VALUES('$from', '$to', '$ID', '$currency1', '$currency2', '$amount','$note', '$rate') ") 
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Why am I getting this error? I copied this script from another area of my site where it works, I just changed the values.

Comment: This is not related to your issue, but some advice. Don't use MySQL, take a look at mysqli and PDO. Secondly, don't but values directly into SQL, look at prepared statements.

Comment: remove the single quotes around $ID

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FROM` is a reserved word in MySQL (and SQL in general). If you really have a column named `FROM` you should wrap it with `` ` `` (backticks) so the parser knows you mean a name:

```
INSERT INTO WIRET (`FROM`, TO, ID, CURRENCY1, ...
```

Comment: It's best not to use any of the [MySQL reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) as column names for this reason.

Comment: @tadman I in the other hand like to wrap everything. The same way you have to wrap strings in any language, it feels only logical that names should be wrapped in SQL. `mysqldump` does it, and I do it too.

Answer (score 1):

If your column is named `from` you have to put it into "`" (backticks) because `FROM` is also a SQL keyword.

By putting a keyword (`FROM`here) into backticks you say "this is not a SQL keyword" to the DBMS.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO WIRET (`FROM`,TO,ID,...
```

Comment: To be a little more precise, the identifier `FROM` needs to be enclosed in backticks because `FROM` is on the MySQL "Reserved Words"  list. (That is, some SQL keywords (e.g. `DATE`) do not need to be enclosed in backticks when used as an identifiers, because they are not on the Reserved Words list.)